# How to reboot a remote dedicated server using php script or php shell client?

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

I am looking into a way to reboot a remote dedicated server using php. While doing research on Google I read about Python shell client. Is there is something similar in php?

Can I use php to reboot a remote server using shell commands? and what is needed to do so?

Comment: You need the information how to call external shell script from PHP?

Comment: yes or connect to remote shell server and execute reboot command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want a web based shell implemented in php.
In that case you can look at this http://ajaxshell.sourceforge.net/
and this http://sourceforge.net/projects/ajaxshell/

Using these scripts you can run arbitrary shell commands.
But remember 2 things.
1. password protect the web shell app
2. The shell will run commands as the apache user. If you want to reboot the server, apache may need root privileges. Running apache as root is usually considered as not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can, by using exec(), passthru() etc. Is it a good idea, I'm not sure : you'll have to give reboot privileges (I don't know exactly, but it's almost root...) to your php user.

Just to  be sure, what you want to do is to call a web page that will reboot your server, or it's more complicated that that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a shell equivilent for PHP. I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell, you can even easily get a shell with root. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
//if PHP is running on the server you want to reboot:
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);

//if PHP needs to SSH to the server first
$shell = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getRemoteHost('ip_address')->getShellBySsh('username', 'password');

$strCmd = "reboot";
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd($strCmd);
```